# How do I fix this python Calculator Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, calculator

Thanks for the help in advance. i need help with my calculator. Thanksssssssss
This is the error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1883, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Benjamin Stuff/BENS CALCULATOR.py", line 42, in 
lambda e, s=self, storeObj=display: s.calc(storeObj), '+')
AttributeError: 'app' object has no attribute 'calc'

> > > 

Code:

```
from tkinter import*

def iCalc (source, side):
    storeObj = Frame(source, borderwidth = 1, bd= 4, bg="sky blue")
    storeObj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return storeObj

def button (source, side, text, command=None):
    storeObj = Button(source, text=text, command=command)
    storeObj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return storeObj
class app(Frame):
    
        def __init__(self):
            Frame.__init__(self)
            self.option_add('*font', 'Comic 20 bold')
            self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
            self.master.title('Bens Calculator')
        
            display = StringVar()
            Entry(self, relief=FLAT,
                  textvariable=display,justify='right',bd=30,bg='sky blue').pack(side=TOP, expand=YES,
                          fill=BOTH)
        
            for clearBut in (["CE"], ["C"]):
                erase = iCalc(self,TOP)
                for ichar in clearBut:
                    button(erase, LEFT, ichar,
                           lambda storeObj=display, q=ichar: storeObj.set(''))
        
            for NumBut in ("789%", "456x", "123+", "0.+"):
                FunctionNum = iCalc(self, TOP)
                for char in NumBut:
                    button(FunctionNum, LEFT, char,
                       lambda storeObj=display, q=char: storeObj.set(storeObj.get() + q))
        
            EqualsButton = iCalc(self, TOP)
            for iEquals in '=':
                if iEquals == '=':
                    btniEquals = button(EqualsButton, LEFT, iEquals)
                    btniEquals.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',
                                    lambda e, s=self, storeObj=display: s.calc(storeObj), '+')
        
                else:
                    btniEquals = button(EqualsButton, LEFT, iEquals,
                       lambda storeObj=display, s='  %s  '%iEquals: storeObj.set(storeObj.get()+s))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app().mainloop()

def calc(self, display):
     try:
        display.set(eval(display.get()))
     except:
        display.set("ERROR")
```

I'm making a calculator if that helps. It happens when I press the equals button. Any Help would be amazing. THANK YOUUU. and have a good day....

Comment: `lambda e, s=self, storeObj=display: s.calc(storeObj), '+')` well, `s=self` so `s.calc()` mean `self.calc()` and `self` is your `app` class, and is there any `app.calc()` ?

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the object of class "`app`" has no method or attribute "`calc`". You need to create a method in `app` class with name "`calc`".

```
from tkinter import*

def iCalc (source, side):
    storeObj = Frame(source, borderwidth = 1, bd= 4, bg="sky blue")
    storeObj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return storeObj

def button (source, side, text, command=None):
    storeObj = Button(source, text=text, command=command)
    storeObj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return storeObj

class app(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.option_add('*font', 'Comic 20 bold')
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title('Bens Calculator')
    
        display = StringVar()
        Entry(self, relief=FLAT,
              textvariable=display,justify='right',bd=30,bg='sky blue').pack(side=TOP, expand=YES,
                      fill=BOTH)
    
        for clearBut in (["CE"], ["C"]):
            erase = iCalc(self,TOP)
            for ichar in clearBut:
                button(erase, LEFT, ichar,
                       lambda storeObj=display, q=ichar: storeObj.set(''))
    
        for NumBut in ("789%", "456x", "123+", "0.+"):
            FunctionNum = iCalc(self, TOP)
            for char in NumBut:
                button(FunctionNum, LEFT, char,
                   lambda storeObj=display, q=char: storeObj.set(storeObj.get() + q))
    
        EqualsButton = iCalc(self, TOP)
        for iEquals in '=':
            if iEquals == '=':
                btniEquals = button(EqualsButton, LEFT, iEquals)
                btniEquals.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',
                                lambda e, s=self, storeObj=display: s.calc(storeObj), '+')
    
            else:
                btniEquals = button(EqualsButton, LEFT, iEquals,
                   lambda storeObj=display, s='  %s  '%iEquals: storeObj.set(storeObj.get()+s))
    
    def calc(self, display):
        try:
            display.set(eval(display.get()))
        except:
            display.set("ERROR")

if __name__=='__main__':
    app().mainloop()
```

Comment: What is an attribute? https://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php

Comment: An attribute is an instance variable defined in the class. Since `calc` is being used a function in the given code, I suggested to create a method.

Comment: I just wanted to leave this link for completness here. There could be the question, but thanks.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Thanks!

Comment: how do you create a method? im very new to python so idk how :/

Comment: Here's a link that can help - https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

Comment: i didnt really understand it. can you tell me the code?

Comment: and also where would i add it in to the scrip?

Comment: Please see my update above. I have added the method for your reference.

Comment: what do i add after "def calc(self):"?